# Is a thread still running or is it just LINQPad?

Tags: c#, multithreading, linqpad

**Disclaimer 1:** I understand the concept of multithreading but the correct implementation still eludes me.

**Disclaimer 2:** I am not criticizing LINQPad at all because it is amazing. I am just trying to find out if I am missing something.

Given the code below, is a thread still running when `Console.WriteLine("Completed");` is called?

I ask because when I run in LINQPad I see *Press Ctrl+Shift+F5 to cancel all threads* in the bottom right hand corner, however, when I run the same code as a console application through VS, it seems to terminate. It is entirely possible I am not using Tasks correctly and/or not terminating them correctly.

```
public class TaskRunner
{
    public async void RunTasks()
    {
        CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        CancellationToken ct = cts.Token;

        Task loadingTask =
            new Task(() =>
                {
                    //do something that takes a while, ie. database or service call
                    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                    {
                        Thread.Sleep(100);
                        Console.WriteLine("Loading");
                    }
                });

        Task entertainmentTask =
            new Task(() =>
                {
                    //do something until told to stop to keep user entertained
                    while (true)
                    {
                        if (ct.IsCancellationRequested)
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                        Console.WriteLine("Entertainment");
                        Thread.Sleep(50);
                    }
                }, ct);

        loadingTask.Start();
        entertainmentTask.Start();

        await Task.WhenAny(loadingTask, entertainmentTask);
        cts.Cancel();

        Console.WriteLine("Completed");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unlike ordinary executables that you build in Visual Studio, LINQPad keeps the process and application alive after the main thread has completed, and this means that background threads will continue to run.

Furthermore, LINQPad recycles the same process/AppDomain when you re-run the query. This is a performance optimization, and also you to cache data between query runs, using LINQPad's Util.Cache method. For instance:

```
void Main()
{
   Util.Cache (TakesSomeTime).Dump();
}

int TakesSomeTime()
{
   Thread.Sleep(2000);
   return 42;
}
```

The first time this query runs, it takes two seconds. Subsequent executions are instant.

Comment: I think I understand I just want to word it another way. When Console.WriteLine("Completed") is hit, the program would be done in a traditional executable, but LINQPad keeps the threads alive to optimize for any future runs and there is not necessarily anything wrong in the code?

Comment: That's correct. In a traditional executable, all background threads terminate when all foreground threads complete. The main thread is a foreground thread, and Tasks use background threads unless instructed otherwise.